# How RBG triplet value is converted into single value? single value comes between 0 to 255. how single value is mapped into color image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, color-theory

Using OpenCV, input image(Blue background image Christmas tree inside) was read.

Below image is input image.

[image]

the output of read image is changed from a blue background into the red.

[image]

when I viewed the value of the variable of 'image' in spyder. Here 3 is RGB channel

[image]
When double-clicked the value it shows with Axis =0. what I understood is BGR value

[image]

Axis =1 here to0 BGR

[image]

Axis =2. I am stuck here. I would not understand how triplet value of(pixel) RBG value is converted into a single value of each pixel and how this pixel(0,0)=254 represents red color here.

[image]

I understood for black and white values varies from 0 to 255. But here how axis =2 (pixel(0,0)=254) represents Red color(guessing from output of the read image).

Answer (score 1):

You are reading image using **OpenCV** where it takes BGR color channel matrix. However you are displaying it using some other library which take color channel matrix as RGB. Convert your image to RGB using `cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.BGR2RGB)` and it will then display it.

Comment: thank you for your answer. my question is math behind each pixel. I understood your answer. For black and white image each pixel varies from 0 to 255 from black to white. What I would like to know is for color image how they are converting triplet BGR or RGB to a single value(which varies from  0 to 255)Refer Asix=2 image.

Comment: I read image using OpenCv `image=cv2.imread('bluebackground.jpg')` .

Comment: I read image using OpenCv `image=cv2.imread('bluebackground.jpg')` . Please explain the screenshot I have displayed. I read `(R, G, B)=image[0,0]` output is `R=254, G= 0, B=0`. Axis =2 screenshot '(0,0) =254' which is Red. If we see each pixel value it showing R value only in Axis=2. What is Axis =0,1?

Comment: Axis 0,1 are representing Blue and Green colors, while axis 2 is representing Red color channel. if Axis 0,1 are equal to zero, it means there is no Blue and Green color in the image. (0, 0, 254) represent that there is only red color in the image.

Comment: display image using cv2.imshow function and check the RGB pixel values. Then, you will understand this.